# JavaScript didn't work on 4.4+,This is Android WebView's bug?

Tags: android, webview

This js code "javascript:document.getElementById('display-name').value='123456';" worked on 4.3 and lower is good, but on 4.4 upper is bad!

4.4 upper show a blank page with '123456'

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                // this line work on 4.3 and lower is good
                // but on 4.4 upper is bad!
                view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('display-name').value='123456';");
            }
        });
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        // use firefox agent
        settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0");
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    }
}
```

by the way...the logcat info like this
"Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering"
what happend? I donot use them any way...
I change the AppCompatActivity to Activity.this error is gone...

Comment: I am form China.The netword is bad,and My English is bad too..

Comment: If you know this Question.please show it to me.Thanks.